# Spilled water on Macbook Pro and dropped it -- now won't boot

Tags: hard-drive, mac, boot, laptop, macbook

I spilled a fair amount of water (about a glass on the keyboard of my late 2008 macbook pro). After flipping the computer over, I let it dry after taking out the battery. As I was walking away, I saw it drop about 3 feet onto the ground from the position it was in. More bad luck!

Anyway, after dissembling it and drying it out (the logic board appeared not to have any water on it because it was still uniformly dusty). I then let it dry for about 7 hours with everything open on it (the logic board removed).

Now it boots up to the equivalent of BIOS. Mine is dual booted so Windows and Mac come up. I cannot boot to either though.

I really hope this is harddrive failure. Could this be failure in anything else? The speakers work fine and I hear the boot noise. Can the motherboard still be dead? What else could cause this?

---

EDIT

I put my Hard Drive into my desktop and it seems to be fine.

I put in another harddrive with linux installed into my macbook pro and it comes up with a black screen. When I hold down alt it boots to bios with "windows" as one of the disks.

Additionally, the logic board seems pretty hot, but does not burn my hand.

Any ideas?

Comment: Quickest way to diagnose would be to take out the HDD and plug into another computer AND/OR boot a Live CD (like Ubuntu) or a flash drive, and boot that. That'll help confirm a HDD failure (or not).

Comment: thanks! I will take the drive and put it into my desktop

Comment: However I cannot boot a live CD as my dvd drive doesn't work in the macbook

Comment: additionally the motherboard heats up a lot. not sure if it's a normal amount

Comment: just edited the question @studiohack with latest results.. thanks for all the help!

Comment: hmmm, sounds complicated :/ Not sure how to go from there. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was not HDD failure in my case. The HDD did not boot up when plugged into another computer (perhaps because the second computer was not a mac maybe). The HDD still worked after getting wiped however. The mother board shorted out in my case.